# Bug in replacingOccurrences()?

Tags: swift

I wonder if the String function replacingOccurrences(of: String, with: String) has a bug:

```
let s = "Hello     World!"
let cleaned : String = s.replacingOccurrences(of: "  ", with: " ")
print("cleaned = '\(cleaned)'")
```

I want to replace multi spaces into one

```
"  " to " "
```

but the string remain the same. I've done that hundreds of times in obj-c, so is this a bug in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **not** a bug. You are replacing every occurrence of 2 spaces with one space. The method does not work recursively, so the 5 spaces are reduced to 3.

You could use regular expression, it replaces all occurrences of one or more spaces with one space:

```
let s = "Hello     World!"
let cleaned = s.replacingOccurrences(of: " +", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
print("cleaned = '\(cleaned)'")
```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Vadian, this is not a bug, this is how your code should work.

And here is another way to get the same result:

```
let cleaned = s.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).filter({ !$0.isEmpty }).joined(separator: " ")
```

You first separate the string by whitespace, then exclude all whitespaces using `filter`, then join the words of the string separating them by whitespaces.

Comment: thanks. Accepted @Vadian's answer just before seeing yours