# replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "") Not Working

Tags: swift, string

I have a text field where a user enters their phone number. When they hit the 'continue' button, the text in the text field is assigned to a global variable called phoneNumber. I then proceed to clean the string of any non-integer values such as '-', ')', and '+'. When I try to delete spaces it doesn't always work. I realized it only doesn't work when I autofill my phone number. Are spaces in autofill phone numbers different than spaces from our keyboards?

Can someone help me figure out what's happening here or if there's a better way to do this?

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberTextField: UITextField!
var phoneNumber = ""

@IBAction func continueButton(_ sender: Any) {

    self.phoneNumber = phoneNumberTextField.text!

    for _ in 0...phoneNumber.count {
    self.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    self.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
    self.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
    self.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
    }

    checkCount(phoneNumber: self.phoneNumber)
}

func checkCount(phoneNumber : String) {
        if phoneNumber.count == 11 {
            self.phoneNumber = "+" + phoneNumber
        }
        else if phoneNumber.count == 10 {
            self.phoneNumber = "+1" + phoneNumber
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bug in replacingOccurrences()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846627/bug-in-replacingoccurrences)

Comment: I tried that it didn't work.

Comment: The reason that your code does not work is probably that the phone number contain “non-breaking space characters”, compare [Why Strings are not equal in my case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48795085/1187415).

Comment: Thanks @MartinR that's probably what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to filter the phone numbers from the string using `CharacterSet` instead of `replacingOccurrences`.

You can try using following code

```
let components =
    phoneNumber.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
let phone = components.joined()
print(phone)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! You're awesome. One little thing I changed, just so I would have one less variable: I changed 'let phone' to 'self.phoneNumber'. That way I didn't have to change the rest of my code. Thanks!